# Can't populate collection from db without DependencyProperty failure

Tags: c#, wpf

I stuck for 3 days with binding collection from my database as a property to datagrid in WPF although I did it before.
To put it simply, I have a viewmodel with a DependencyProperty "CurrentRecord" keeping database record number of a record to work with in this viewmodel instance. It is set in a moment of initializing with another class:

> internal void load_Record(records selected_record)
> {
> RecordViewModel vm = new RecordViewModel();
> vm.CurrentRecord = selected_record;
> RecordBase recordbase = new RecordBase(); //usercontrol = view
> recordbase.DataContext = vm; ....}

Everything works well here.

My ViewModel properties:

```cs
public int record_id
{
    get { return CurrentRecord.record_id; }
}

private ObservableCollection<procedure_record> procedures;
public ObservableCollection<procedure_record> Procedures
{
    get { return procedures; }
    set { procedures = value; }
}
public ICollectionView Procedures_collection { get; set; }
```

And the constructor

```cs
public RecordViewModel()
{
    UserControl_Loaded();
    procedures = new ObservableCollection<procedure_record>();
    Procedures_collection = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Procedures);
    Procedures_collection.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("initiation_date", 
        ListSortDirection.Ascending));
}
```

Still works well. Application can display record_id in a textblock. But if I try to populate collection it crashes:

```cs
if (procedures == null)
{
    using (var db = new MainEntityModel())
    {
        var query = from pm in db.procedure_record
                    where pm.record_id == this.record_id
                    select pm;

        foreach (var p in query)
        {
            procedures.Add((procedure_record)p);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried put this code in the constructor (or invoke as a separate class method) and got an error with DependencyProperty! (why is it??) It is @System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' at the line get { return CurrentRecord.record_id; } - CurrentRecord.get returned null. Can't find connection between this events. Also can't populate collection do show data in XAML dataGrid. XAML:

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Procedures_collection}" .../>
```

Ask for your help!

UPDATE

```cs
public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentRecordProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentRecord", 
        typeof(records), 
        typeof(RecordViewModel));

public records CurrentRecord
{
    get
    {
        return (records)GetValue(CurrentRecordProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(CurrentRecordProperty, value);
    }
}

public int record_id
{
    get { return CurrentRecord.record_id; }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your class records too, pls?

Comment: You get the exception because CurrentRecord is null. As a note, you don't typically have dependency properties in view models. They are used in view elements, e.g. controls, where you need properties to be bindable. A view model would usually expose ordinary CLR properties and implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var query = (from pm in db.procedure_record
                            where pm.record_id == record_id
                            select pm).ToList();  

 
if( query !=null) Procedures = new ObservableCollection<procedure_record>(query);
```

Comment: It helps a bit. The error disappeared but datagrid is empty. I still can't figure out how query and dependency property are connected.

Comment: Get the same error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' with  "get { return CurrentRecord.record_id; }" line. If constructor has a query it crashes

Comment: I found a line causing this trouble:   "where pm.record_id == this.record_id"  If I coment it UserControl runs (with emptydatagrid... but runs). How to fix that?

Comment: You certainly don't need a word  this. But I don't know know  how you get  record_id. If it is 0 your query will be null and everything will crash.

Comment: Thanks. Updated my answer (put there more code). It is a dependency property, viewmodel gets in in a moment of initializing with help of another viewmodel class and can't be null. Without error-causing line usercontrol displays record_id always. Maybe LINQ query can't work with dependency properties.

Comment: Linq don't care if it a dependency property. Did you check what is  record_id value?

Comment: Thanks to you, I solved the problem. The issue was I put my query in a constructor but gave value of CurrentRecord property to this class in the next line of code after initialization of a class. I changed constructor and add 1 input parameter, instead of "RecordViewModel vm = new RecordViewModel();
vm.CurrentRecord = selected_record"; made "RecordViewModel vm = new RecordViewModel(selected_record);". Everything works fine. Thanks!